# Python Turtle window - Set (or get) exact pixel size of window accounting for borders?

Tags: python, python-turtle

I'm working on a graphical python program that involves drawing with turtles -- and for which I'd like to be able to center an element with a small padding bar around the edge of the window. However, because (in my best guess) of the borders drawn around the window, the actual pixel count of the screen is "off" by a few, and in an annoying way -- the top/left seems to be exactly what you'd expect (i.e. for a 600x600 screen, the top left pixel is (-300, 300), but the bottom/right is smaller (more like 290,-290).

I can of course fix this by a guess-and-check "fudge factor," but I'm wondering if there is a way to fix this properly -- that is, to either know the exact size of the borders drawn, know the position of the bottom/rightmost visible pixel, etc.

As an example, this code *should* draw a box that is centered in a 600x600 window, with 15px of padding evenly spaced around it:

```
from turtle import *

#set key size variables and calculate top left position
pixels = 600
padding = 15
top_left = [(-pixels/2)+padding, (pixels/2)-padding]
line_size = pixels - 2*padding

#Make screen and get width and height
my_screen = Screen()
my_screen.setup(width=pixels, height=pixels)
my_screen.bgcolor("white")

#Draw rectangle that should be 15px from each edge of window
t = Turtle()
t.speed(0)
t.teleport(*top_left)
x = 0
t.begin_fill()
while x < 4:
    t.fd(line_size)
    t.rt(90)
    x += 1
t.end_fill()

#Check to see if I can get a real window size somehow?
print(my_screen.window_width()) #prints "600"
print(my_screen.window_height()) #prints "600"
print(my_screen.screensize()) #prints "(400, 300)"

my_screen.exitonclick()
```

However, [as you can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCHmy.png), it actually draws a box that is slightly offset to the bottom/right.  The last block of code there was my way of seeing whether any of the size-getting functions would return an accurate screen size (which is probably something along the lines of 590x590, but they either return 600x600 or 400x300 -- neither of which help.

Comment: instead of 3 lines `x = 0`, `while x < 4:` , `x += 1` you can use one `for x in range(4):`

Comment: Ha thanks furas! I always forget that for some reason!

Answer (score 2):

I have actually answered my own question, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36029529/make-python-turtle-window-size-same-as-canvas-size) older answer to a similar question -- that I didn't quite grasp on first read. I'll leave this up to help others.

The answer is to wrap the turtle screen inside a tkinter canvas, then to use `setworldcoordinates` to set the turtle screen coordinates to what you think they should be -- it doesn't matter if this doesn't match perfectly with the underlying tkinter window coordinates. So, this works perfectly:

```
import tkinter as tk
from turtle import *

pixels = 600
padding = 15
left, top = -pixels/2+padding, pixels/2-padding
line_size = pixels - 2*padding


root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=pixels, height=pixels)
canvas.pack()

my_screen = TurtleScreen(canvas)
my_screen.setworldcoordinates(-pixels/2, -pixels/2, pixels/2, pixels/2)
my_screen.bgcolor('white')

t = RawTurtle(my_screen)
t.speed(5)
t.teleport(left, top)
t.setheading(0)
t.begin_fill()
for x in range(4):
    t.fd(line_size)
    t.rt(90)
t.end_fill()

my_screen.mainloop()
```

(As an aside, if you just try using setworldcoordinates on a turtle-drawn window *without* wrapping in in a tkinter canvas, it doesn't work perfectly, as turtle (for some reason) pads the top and left side with extra pixels.)

Comment: Hehe I did now, and I see why you asked! Thanks for that one!